# MySQL container respawns automatically when stopped

Tags: docker, containers

I have installed Docker do play around and cannot find a simple way to just remove container. Container was created as a service:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    profiles:
        image: mysql:8.0.3
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_root_pwd
        secrets:
            - mysql_root_pwd

secrets:
    mysql_root_pwd:
        file: /run/secrets/mysql_root_pwd
        external: true
```

However, I cannot find a simple way to stop it (searched high and low around).

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
fc0bb42c3b1f        mysql@sha256:21cc59a132e029c688734a66b50bfa7e5b31af9f2f19267f463c247d51c67b5a   "docker-entrypoint..."   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        3306/tcp            mysql803.1.t5zko7miwnkt37qk1ch6ubvmj
```

When I issue a `stop` command, I get a different container ID:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
9359e1e6ac3b        mysql@sha256:21cc59a132e029c688734a66b50bfa7e5b31af9f2f19267f463c247d51c67b5a   "docker-entrypoint..."   2 seconds ago       Created                                        mysql803.1.i7bktrg7631aetonf09nzahsk
fc0bb42c3b1f        mysql@sha256:21cc59a132e029c688734a66b50bfa7e5b31af9f2f19267f463c247d51c67b5a   "docker-entrypoint..."   6 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                       mysql803.1.t5zko7miwnkt37qk1ch6ubvmj
```

Obviously, I tried setting the `RestartPolicy`:

```
sudo docker update --restart=no 9359e1e6ac3b
```

**Before:**

```
"RestartPolicy": {
    "Name": "",
    "MaximumRetryCount": 0
},
```

**After:**

```
"RestartPolicy": {
    "Name": "no",
    "MaximumRetryCount": 0
},
```

But, again, stopping this container causes a new one to respawn. I have tried restarting Docker daemon as well, but without success.

**Can anyone point in a right direction of resolving this silly issue?**

**Update:**

Forgot to mention Docker specific info, which might be of use:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Thu Nov  2 20:40:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Thu Nov  2 20:40:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly of me, I've found what I missed and I am posting it here in case someone else stumbles upon the same scenario.

What I tried is to stop a container, which was a part of a service with 1 replica. In response, service would respawn a new one.

Instead of talking to a container, I needed to do it to a service. So, this resolved the isssue:

```
> sudo docker service ls
ID            NAME      MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
msczwypom56z  mysql803  replicated  1/1       mysql:8.0.3

> sudo docker service ps msczwypom56z
ID            NAME            IMAGE        NODE    DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE                ERROR                        PORTS
zkxlb9k04hb0  mysql803.1      mysql:8.0.3  ubuntu  Running        Running about a minute ago                                
hczlxonvykvs   \_ mysql803.1  mysql:8.0.3  ubuntu  Shutdown       Failed about a minute ago    "task: non-zero exit (137)"  
w3i3yrxvbokd   \_ mysql803.1  mysql:8.0.3  ubuntu  Shutdown       Shutdown about a minute ago                               
774squpmwnqf   \_ mysql803.1  mysql:8.0.3  ubuntu  Shutdown       Complete 4 minutes ago                                    
t5zko7miwnkt   \_ mysql803.1  mysql:8.0.3  ubuntu  Shutdown       Complete 5 minutes ago

# Not sure if this was needed at all
sudo docker service update --restart-condition=none msczwypom56z

# Finally, remove it
sudo docker service rm msczwypom56z
```

After running a `docker ps` command no new container were shown.

Hope this helps to someone...